# CFA: Fixing the loading of the observed variables on the error factors to one vs. fixing the variance of the error terms to one

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

In most (all?) structural equation modelling software the default to scaling the *error* variables is to fix the loadings of the observed variables on the error variables to unity and freely estimate the error variances. In contrast, the scale (i.e., variance) of the exogenous latent variable is often fixed to one. I wonder why the same logic isn't applied to the error variables so that their variance is fixed to unity (implying an identity matrix of the error terms) and the loading of the observed variables on the error variables is freely estimated. Is there a mathematical reason for that?